# Process video file in parallel

Tags: matlab, video-processing, parfor

I'm trying to read a 25 second long video file in Matlab and trying to process it in parallel using parfor. I'm trying to split it into 5 shorter videos, each of 5 seconds length. Here is the code for that:-

```
mov = VideoReader('movie.avi');

parfor i=1:5

    vd(i)=read(mov,[(i-1)*5+1, (i)*5]);
    current_frame=0;
    while hasFrame(vd(i))
        current_frame=current_frame+1;            
        vidFrame = readFrame(vd(i));
        fprintf('%d part, frame no %d\n',i,current_frame);
    end
end
```

I keep getting this error on the first line inside parfor loop.

> Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch

How do I retrieve what is coming from read function into the frame variable `vd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to store something [that is not a scalar](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.read.html#inputarg_index) (`read(mov, [start, stop])`) into something that *is* a scalar (`vd(i)`). You likely want to make `vd` a cell array so that each element can hold something of an arbitrary size/dimension.

```
vd{k} = read(mov, [(k-1)*5+1, (k)*5]);
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew what the problem was but I kept trying to add colon as first three dimensions to accomodate rgb values. Anyways, this solved it but now I'm facing the following issue:- An UndefinedFunction error was thrown on the workers for 'hasFrame'.  This might be because the file
containing 'hasFrame' is not accessible on the workers.  Use addAttachedFiles(pool, files) to specify the
required files to be attached.  See the documentation for 'parallel.Pool/addAttachedFiles' for more
details. Any idea about that or should I ask a new question for this?

Comment: @ChintanTrivedi The output of `read` is not a `VideoReader` object and therefore doesn't have a `hasFrame` method. You will simply want to determine what the output *does* look like and loop through that.